# CSS animation appear on top while running

Tags: html, css, vue.js, position, css-animations

I'm animating 2 blinking eyes. But they appear on top of my navigation bar when I scroll the page. It doesn't do that without the animation. How can I make the animation run under the navigation bar? Some posts mentioned z-index but I can't seem to make it work.
I replicated the problem here: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: can you please add `z-index:10` to your `.nav` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited your code as follows:

```
<script setup>

</script>

<template>
<div class="nav">
  navigation bar
</div>
<div class="face">
<div class="eyes">
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  
  </div>
</template>

<style>
 @keyframes blink {
    0% {transform: scaleY(0.1) scaleX(1.4);}
    5% {transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);}
    10% {transform: scaleY(0.1) scaleX(1.4);}
    15% {transform: scaleY(1) scaleX(1);}
  }
  .face {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 50px 100px;
  }
  .eyes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 100px;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
  }
  .eyes div {
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    animation: blink 3s linear 0.0001s infinite;
  }
  .nav{
    background-color: pink;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
     left: 0;
     right: 0;
    z-index: 100;
  }
  .content {
    height: 1000px
  }
</style>
```

Here, I have added a `z-index: 100` so that the nav bar always remains at the top.

Comment: It would be helpful to future readers if you could give an explanation of why your solution works, and also if you could make it into a runnable snippet.

Comment: My post has been updated